# Did I use the wrong adb permissions for apps to not get killed in the background?

Tags: android, background, adb

Hi so I'm new to this whole adb thing and used this code cmd appops set <package_name> RUN_ANY_IN_BACKGROUND allow in adb shell since I have android 10 then I restarted my phone. So far I think it doesn't work is there a specific command that I should use for this that I missed for some reason.

Comment: `appops set package-name RUN_ANY_IN_BACKGROUND allow` - not `allowed` ([source](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/power/app_mgmt#testing-app-restrictions))

Comment: Sorry meant by allow changed the comand

Answer (score 0):

To manually apply background restrictions, run this command:

$ adb shell cmd appops set packagename RUN_ANY_IN_BACKGROUND ignore

To remove background restrictions, run this command:

$ adb shell cmd appops set packagename RUN_ANY_IN_BACKGROUND allow

Comment: Yes but the thing is I didn't put any restrictions on the app in the first place I just want the app to stop being killed in the background but it seems the command that I type in didn't work. So I'm looking if there another command that I could try.